# How is it proved, that antediluvian people didn't live for hundreds of years?

Tags: lifespan

Bible says that antediluvian people lived for 800-900 of years. Nowadays apologists say that it is possible and that we just can't know the truth.

I know that one of the basic science principles is the suggestion of similarity of laws of nature. I.e. if we see ancient human fossils, similar to modern human remnants, then we should expect they are of similar age.

But does science have some other age proofs besides this?

May be, for example, from migration data or from some other sources?

Isn't it possible in principle, that some virus epidemic in ancient times cause humans to live shorter, due to virus DNA embedded into all of the human DNAs?

**UPDATE**

We don't know abut the all reasons of aging and also we don't know about all means of horizontal gene transfer.

What if, a lifespan is a feature, which can be transferred horizontally by a virus or somehow else?

Comment: As @MCM mentions below, parsimony dictates assuming that the ages reported in the Old Testament are not literal years. I think an interesting variant of this question, and one that is more amenable to (anthropological) study, is _why do so many ancient cultures think of their elders as having superhuman lifespans?_ Both Cree (indigenous to North America) and Jainists (mostly in Asia) think there are earlier epochs where humans lived multiple centuries.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.

Comment: For my own curiosity, do you have a reference of the philosophy of science stating the role of "similarity of laws of natural" as having a key role in science?

Answer (score 7):

> I know that one of the basic science principles is the suggestion of similarity of laws of nature. I.e. if we see ancient human fossils, similar to modern human remnants, then we should expect they are of similar age.

Well, similar physiology. Modern humans, throughout recorded history, rarely broke the 100-years-old mark. Our evolutionary cousins [rarely break half of that](http://pin.primate.wisc.edu/factsheets/entry/chimpanzee) and in the wild [reach old age at our "Middle Age" equivalent.](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/apes/gorilla/)

So, knowing that *as we are* is exceptionally long-lived for members of our clade, it would be absolutely incredible and far beyond expectations for an evolutionary ancestor to live **8x-9x** longer than some of the longest-lived members of our tree (and would be one of the longest living complex organisms *ever*).

Impossible? No. We can only interpret data from the past; we do not have any records from the time period. In that way, you're entirely correct if you're looking for additional proof.

> But does science have some other age proofs besides this?

This depends on what you consider 'other' proof. Most of the estimations of age of found fossils relies on comparative morphology: We assume that because our joints and teeth wear-out at a certain rate, we can compare the rate of decay of teeth and joints of fossils and get an estimate. If it's true that our extinct cousins experienced similar wear 'n tear as we do (and we *don't* have any reason to think otherwise; the bones may be slightly different, but they are made up of the same material), then we can use the comparative morphology as a reasonable estimate.

If we assume that their bones and teeth wore out much, *much* slower (it would have to be about 10x slower while also being made of similar material) then our age estimates would have to be adjusted.

> May be, for example, from migration data or from some other sources?

Migration data would be incredibly difficult to produce. You would have to follow one family as they migrated, and fossils are rare enough as-is. Data like that would be practically impossible to gather.

Perhaps some Population Geneticist has run some genomic data and is capable of making a similar claim through the molecular clock hypothesis, but I am as-yet unaware of anything like this.

> Isn't it possible in principle, that some virus epidemic in ancient times cause humans to live shorter, due to virus DNA embedded into all of the human DNAs?

In principle? Yes. But there **isn't** any evidence for that. Keep in mind that in order for the viral DNA to be integrated into *all* of humanity then it would have had to infect us when our numbers were very, *very* small. Evidence does show a bottlenecking event in humans [about 70,000 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_bottleneck#Humans) - but this was thought to have been caused by a supervolcano eruption which dramatically changed the environment and *not* a virus. Both genomic and geological evidence come together to support that hypothesis.

So, while you are *correct* that - in *theory* a population of humans could have been infected by a virus which mutated their DNA and caused a dramatic reduction in lifespan at the same time as a bottlenecking event - we have no *other* evidence supporting that, either genomic, geological, or evolutionary.

Given the *lack* of evidence, we should remember our **Occam's Razor** - In the absence of evidence, the simplest explanation is usually the correct one.

So it's either an *exceptionally* long-lived species of an already-long-living family contracted a virus at the same time a bottlenecking event occurred and didn't leave behind any evidence, *or* our ancestors lived about as long as our evolutionary cousins do now and it's *us* who are exceptionally long-lived because of evolutionarily advantageous things like [The Grandmother Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandmother_hypothesis) and advancements in technology - which is supported by genomic evidence, fossil evidence, geological evidence, and recorded history.

We cannot ever *truly* know what happened several hundred thousand years ago. We weren't there and nobody was writing anything down. However, Science is evidence-based, implying that scientific opinion follows the argument with the most supporting evidence behind it.

If the evidence changes and begins to favor another argument, then so will the scientific community (ideally speaking).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I would like to have some "killing" argument, not Occam or Popper like :)

Comment: The substance of the question as-posed is an _appeal to ignorance_ and is therefore fallacious. @MCM's answer is the best form you'll get. You can't 'kill' an argument that presupposes that our current knowledge is irrelevant to the proposition. It's like positing that God is beyond all physical laws, then demanding a scientific experiment to disprove the existence of God. As long as you're asking what is biologically possible (which is unknown) and not what is biologically probable (which a good biologist can contend with) the question cannot be directly addressed.

Comment: @SuzanCioc - The problem is that without some basic assumptions the current scientific understanding can't actually answer your question. What is possible is significantly different from what is supported. If you have questions regarding a *specific* data type - like morphology or genetic data - then you'd get a more specialized and more detailed response. Simply saying "We weren't there so how can we know for sure?" is sort of like trying to prove I'm human and not a computer program despite only communicating online. ;-) In order for things to function, basic things *must* be assumed 'true'.